# Can we use "nor" with "nothing" together?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

> He is a killer! There's nothing to doubt with nor debunk it.

How does it sound? Since my Grammarly keyboard didn't correct my sentence, I think it's fine? Although, I've never heard or seen "**nothing + ... + nor**". What I've known, **nor** is used with **neither** or **not** (at least that's what my dictionary told me). I'm assuming I can use **nor** since my sentence sounds rather negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use **nor** with **nothing**. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nor), it can be used in a list after **neither**, or on its own as a replacement for **neither**.

If you want to use it, you would have to say:

> There is neither anything to doubt nor anything to debunk it.

Alternatively, you could say:

> There is nothing to doubt and nothing to debunk it.

---

The word **with** is not required in your sentence.

It is unusual to say that something cannot be debunked: debunk has overtones that the thing to be debunked has been misrepresented, and in this case the speaker would not want to suggest that their opinion is a misrepresentation.
**disprove** might be a better word to use in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can absolutely use **nor** with **nothing**. Remove the word **with** from your sentence and you're good to go.
See this answer on a similar question https://english.stackexchange.com/a/106796